# What's the best approach for using ajaxform with jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, ajaxform

I'm using the **[ajaxform](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)** jQuery plugin to create ajaxed HTML forms and want to implement validation using the jQuery **[Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)** plugin.

I'm not sure what is the best way to implement this.

It doesn't work out-of-the-box for me. I set up the form with `form.ajaxform({})` and then set up validation with `form.validate({})`. The invalidHandler event fires on the validation plugin, but ajaxform still submits the form.

***How do I wire the two up properly?***

---

**My code:**

```
_initializeValidation: function (form) {

    var options = {
        rules:
            {
                Name:
                {
                    required: true
                }
            },
        messages:
            {
                Name: "Name is required",
                ShortName: "Short name is required"
            }
    };

    if (form.find("#ShortName").length == 1)
        $.extend(options.rules, { ShortName: { required: true} });

    form.validate(options);
}

/* 
*   Initializes a newly loaded edit form
*/
_initializeEdit: function (panel) {
    var thisDetailTab = this;
    var form = panel.find("form");
    form.ajaxForm(
        {
            target: panel,
            url: this._config.updateUrl,
            beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) {
                return form.valid();
            },
            success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
                thisDetailTab._initializeDetails(panel);
                thisDetailTab._config.refreshSummary();
            }
        }
    );

    this._initializeValidation(form);

    var cancelButton = panel.find(".cancelButton");
    cancelButton.click(function (event) {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: thisDetailTab._config.detailsUrl,
                success: function (data) {
                    panel.empty();
                    panel.append(data);
                    thisDetailTab._initializeDetails(panel);
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you paste some code about how you're using the ajaxform? I have experience with the validation plugin but not with ajaxform :(

Comment: I've now added the `valid()` call to the beforeSubmit event. It seems to do what I want, and is fairly simple. For those in the know. Is this approach ok? Any pitfalls? Does a better way exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`.ajaxForm()`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api), use [`.ajaxSubmit()`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) in your [`submitHandler`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) (which only fires on success), like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: { ... },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({ ...options... });
  }
});
```

This way it only attempts to do an AJAX submission if the validation is successful (otherwise the `invalidHandler` is fired).  If you want to see a live example, here's [the related validation plugin demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html).

Comment: Before reading your answer I added a `.valid()` call to `beforeSubmit` which appears to work. Are you aware of any differences, pros/cons between the method you describe and the one I tried?

Comment: @GiddyUpHorsey - either way works, though unless you're removing the `submit` event handler, you may be running validation twice, but that's *usually* ok, if inefficient.